# output unix command 1 to column A , unix command 2 to column B to same .csv file

Tags: bash, unix

i want to make an for loop so it will output each command in 2 columns

example:

hostname and whoami commands will output in .csf file like:

```
     A       |    B 
 <hostname>  |  <username>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `paste` and process substitutions:

```
paste -d'|' <(command1) <(command2) > file
```

Example:

```
paste -d'|' <(printf '%s\n' A "$(hostname)") <(printf '%s\n' B "$(whoami)") > file.csv
```

Or using a loop:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    paste -d'|' <(printf '%s\n' "A$i" "$(hostname)") <(printf '%s\n' "B$i" "$(whoami)")
done > file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, the loop example help me, i just used ',' instead '|'.